# Woocommerce - Change tax class programmatically on Order and recalcluate

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I´m working on a solution to change the tax class based on the country of the customer AND if he can provide a VAT-ID or not.

The store is EU based and providing services to B2B and B2C.
So for all EU based companies that can provide a VAT-ID, no taxes will be charged unless the origin country is the same. 
For all customers who cannot provide a VAT-ID, our local taxes will be added.
And so on...

All solutions I have found are only interacting with the cart, but as I´m creating the order programmatically I need another solution.

Is there a way (a hook maybe) to change the **tax_class** while creating the order?

For testing I tried to add this method but that did not work. It fires the filter but does not change the tax class in the order.

```
function wc_change_tax_class( $tax_class, $product ) {

    $tax_class = 'Zero rate';

    return $tax_class;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_tax_class', 'wc_change_tax_class', 1, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_tax_class', 'wc_change_tax_class', 1, 2 );
```

Also I tried this method in the function that creates the order but with the same result. Nothing happend.

```
$woocommerce->customer->set_is_vat_exempt( true );
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After hours of trying to find the reason, the solution was quite easy:

All solutions I found suggested to write `'Zero rate'` or `'Zero Rate'`. Depending on what the Name was given in the Woocommerce settings. But for me, it does only work if you write it this way `'zero-rate'`. So change the table class name and remove any spaces in the woocommerce settings and of course in the variable.

```
$tax_class = 'zero-rate';
```

Hope that saves someone's time!

Comment: You should accept your answer as it's something helpful.

Comment: After a long seeking I finally found this solution! Thanks man, it's incredible that woocommerce doesn't mind this kind of issue... ;(