# Tax calculation problem for customers with valid EU VAT ID in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I’m using the experimental mode of WooCommerce – the price should always stay the same, only the tax is changing:

My prices are set without taxes, and I'm using [Aelia EU VAT Assistant](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-eu-vat-assistant/) plugin

My tax settings:

- for customers from Canary Islands I want to charge our local tax I.G.I.C 7% – the same for business (with tax-number) as for individuals.
  –>example: price 50 Euros (incl. 7% I.G.I.C tax calculated correctly
- for customers from rest of Spain + EU Countries, I want to charge :
  Corresponding tax of each country if each client
  –>example: price 50 Euros (incl. X% tax depends country calculated correctly )

Using this code:

```php
  add_filter( ‘woocommerce_adjust_non_base_location_prices’, ‘\__return_false’ );
```

Everything was working, until now.

The problem happens, if the customer is a business customer with EU VAT ID number: WooCommerce is extracting the corresponding tax (depending on the country), so for example if price is set to 50 Euros (incl 0% tax), I get 46 Euros, 47 Euros etc… depending on the country.

I've tried already to add different Tax models, Zero vat, etc…, without any luck.

Lastly, I've tried:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_adjust_non_base_location_prices( $true ) { 
    if(WC()->customer->set_is_vat_exempt( true )) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return $true;
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_adjust_non_base_location_prices', 'filter_woocommerce_adjust_non_base_location_prices', 10, 1 );
```

and it works properly, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Any kind of guidance would be very appreciated.

Comment: when using `if( WC()->customer->set_is_vat_exempt( true ) ) {`you are just setting all customers as vat_exempt **and your function will always return `true`** as the method `set_is_vat_exempt()` doesn't return anything… Instead you need to use it this way: `if( WC()->customer->is_vat_exempt() ) {`… You will need to check users to see which are now vat exempt. **That said, I am not sure that it will solve your main problem.**

Answer (score 0):

First thanks to LoicTheAztec for pointing me to the right direction - it looks like I found the solution:

Based on this thread:
[Woocommerce - Change tax class programmatically on Order and recalcluate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59665417/woocommerce-change-tax-class-programmatically-on-order-and-recalcluate)

1. I've added new "zero tax" for everyone - all tax fields are * , tax value 0,0000
2. The code for `funcions.php`

A: Part to keep always same price in WC experimental mode

```
add_filter('woocommerce_adjust_non_base_location_prices', '__return_false');
```

B: part for showing info "tax exempt" to customers

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_tax_totals', 'show_zero_rate_taxes');
function show_zero_rate_taxes($tax_totals) {
  global $woocommerce;
  if (empty( $tax_totals ) && WC()->customer->is_vat_exempt()) {
    $tax_totals['zero-rated'] = (object) array(
      'label'            => 'Exento de IVA',
      'amount'           => 0,
      'formatted_amount' => woocommerce_price( 0 ),
      'name'             => 'Exento de IVA ',
      'is_compound'      => false
    );
  }

  return $tax_totals;
}
```

C: This part for switching tax class, if `WC()->customer->is_vat_exempt()`
--> please keep in mind the slug I'm using - 'tasa-cero', generated by WC in spanish version

```
function wc_change_tax_class( $tax_class, $product ) {
  $tax_class = 'tasa-cero';
  if (WC()->customer->is_vat_exempt()) {
    return $tax_class;
  }
}
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_tax_class', 'wc_change_tax_class', 1, 2);
```

Tested and for the moment everything seems to work...